# What is the difference between expand and include in Linq?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

What is the difference between expand and include in Linq when using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `Expand` extension method is from the WCF Data Services (formerly ADO.net Data Services), which is database and ORM agnostic.  It does not care if you are using Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL, nHibernate, etc.  It will not create table joins, only work with existing data loaded in memory, since it is a higher level abstraction.

`Include`, on the other hand, comes from Entity Framework, and is optimized for creating the proper joins at the database level.

Internally, if you are using `Expand` against an Entity Framework managed Entity, it's likely that it will end up using an overloaded version of `Include` anyway.

In general, unless you are using WCF, you should be using `Include`.